# .NET stack memory limit

Tags: .net, memory, 64-bit, stack, limit

I am using C#, .NET 4.0, 64-bit. I need to store in memory 500 million "data points" that are used in computations. I need to decide whether to create these as struct or class objects. Structs seem so much faster.

Is there a memory limit for the stack? If so, how can it be adjusted.

Will storing so much data on a stack affect the overall performance of the system?

(By the way, I am aware of the single-object size limitation in .NET, so that's being addressed -- the data will be stored in multiple collections).

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing the stack with the heap ?

Comment: On what basis do you claim/assume that structs are "so much faster" than classes?

Comment: I presume OP creates tough relationship between on stack allocation and struct, which is wrong. These are completely different subjects, that *could* be related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. If stack size matters, you're doing something wrong.

If you use many datapoints, you'll put them in a collection, such as an array. Arrays are always allocated on then heap. An array of structs embeds the individual structs and forms a continuous memory block. (If you have more than 2GB, you need several arrays).

Whereas with reference types, the array will only contain the references, and the objects get allocated individually on the heap. A heap allocation has about 16 bytes of overhead, the reference in the array accounts for another 8.
You'll also get worse cache locality due to the indirections, and the GC has to do more work, to crawl all those references.

My conclusion is that if you have many small datapoints, make them a struct, and put them in an array.

Answer (score 4):

You are going to store your data in arrays and arrays are always stored on the heap. So it doesn't matter whether or not you use structs or classes to hold those arrays. You may well want to make sure that your data points are value types (i.e. structs) so that arrays of data points can be allocated efficiently in contiguous blocks of memory.

Performance differences between heap and stack allocated memory are most likely to be seen with small objects that are allocated and deallocated in a short space of time. For long-lived objects of the size you describe, I would expect there to be no difference in performance between stack and heap allocated memory.

Comment: The thing is that if struct is allocated on heap it loses its "benefit" (from question point of view) of fast allocations.

Comment: @Tigran Those differences are going to be unmeasurable once you have performed an operation on 500 million data points.

Comment: @Tigran Not if it is part of an array. Structs will end up in a continuous memory block in the array, whereas classes will get a new instance(with the associated 16 byte overhead) and additional indirections.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: so struct allocated on heap or on stack have the same performance, only if it makes part of array??

Comment: @Tigran value types get embedded into a containing structure. No matter if that's the stack, a class or an array. Reference types only embed a pointer into the containing structure. You should read a bit on what value types are. Eric Lippert has written a lot about that, both on his blog, and here on SO.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I'm perfectly aware of differencies of them. My quesion has nothing to do with it. I'm asking why do you think that struct allocated on heap and the *same* struct allocated on stack should have *no* any difference in terms of performance? Cause that what I understood from your comment before.

Comment: @Tigran Because the performance benefit of structs is unrelated to heap vs. stack. It's about avoiding the overhead of a per-object allocation.

Comment: Understand your point, but do not agree on choosing struct for 500mln elements on which you should make a computation. Immagine acessing that data reading/writing/updating.... **I** would definitely go for reference type with solition provided in my answer.

Comment: @Tigran an array of structs is a reference type allocated on the heap

Comment: @David Hefferman: today I definitely have a difficulty to express my thouught clearly :) I mean accessing value types inside array will make you a copy of those on every read/write acess.

Comment: @Tigran Only if you explicitly make a copy of the value type.

Answer (score 2):

It's surprising that no one seemed to try to answer the actual question.

**I absolutely understand** that this is the wrong question to ask 99.9% of the time, but it would still be interesting to know the results (at least I was curious).

### The test program

It is really simple using unsafe code and the `stackalloc` keyword.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 100; i < Int32.MaxValue; i+=10)
        {
            StackCheck(i);
            Console.WriteLine($"Successfully allocated {i} bytes on the stack");
        }
    }

    public static unsafe void StackCheck(int size)
    {
        byte* array = stackalloc byte[size];
    }
}
```

### Results

Mind that this is 100% implementation detail and may differ by CLR, CLR version, operating system or individual machine. In my experiment both the full .NET Framework 4.7.2 and .NET Core 2.1.4 crashed **just above the 1MB mark**. Interestingly it is **not even consistent between runs**, the results fluctuate by a few hundred bytes.

### Adjusting the stack limit

You cannot change the stack size on an existing thread, but **you can set it on new ones**:

```
Thread testThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int i = 1000; i < Int32.MaxValue; i+=1000)
    {
        StackCheck(i);
        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully allocated {i} bytes on the stack");
    }
}, 200_000_000);
testThread.Start();
testThread.Join();
```

Obviously the whole stack is allocated when you create the thread, if you set it too large, the `Thread` constructor will throw an `OutOfMemoryException`.

But again, this test was done to mainly to satisfy my own curiosity, as others stated don't do this **unless you really really know what you're doing**.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use classes for your data points. In this case, the memory will be allocated on the heap.

But considering that you are talking about 500 million data points, and especially since you are programming in the .NET world with a more restricted memory limit for apps, I would strongly encourage using some kind of embedded database, like sqlite, for example. In this way, you would avoid having all of your data points in memory simultaneously, but only the ones you need for computation *now*.

Comment: In my experience it's common to require fast access to large amounts of data without the overhead of a database. And if you load them all into memory you get 12GB of overhead just for using reference types. Not nice.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: agree. Infact do not load them all in memory, as suggested, but use some `db` layer for holding data.

Comment: Often you want to hold them all in memory for performance reasons. For example I often work with physics simulations where dozens of GBs of data are held in large arrays.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: 500mln objects? In my expirience where I met a workload of such dimensions, usually didn't met real time performance requirements. Let's say it could be true for 99% of cases. Honestly, don-'t think 1% is case of OP's question :) +1